# No matching member function for call to connect

Tags: c++, qt

I have one issue with my C++ code in Qt.
I work for a serial connection between my PC and an Arduino.

The window should display the potentiometer value by a QLCNumber widgets. My class contains `int m_valeurPot` for the potentiometer, and `QLCDNumber *m-afficheValeurPotentiometre` (I declare this in a constructor).

I use Q_Object in my class and i have this line `connect(arduino, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readSerial()))` which work but this line `QObject::connect(m_valeurPot, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), m_afficheValeurPotentiometre, SLOT(display(int)))` doesn't work.

The error says

> no matching member function for call to 'connect'

I have read a similar subject in this forum but the answer doesn't work for me.

Someone can help me ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: What is `valueChanged` what is `display`? Your question does not show the [mcve].

Comment: you are right, `dispay` is a SLOT from QLCDNumber but a have use `valueChanged` with no base. Can i create an emit signal when my int changed value ?
Thanks for link and sorry it's my first post. i will not reproduce this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to connect slot to an signal of int here (but int is a primitive type - it has no signals or slots):
`QObject::connect(m_valeurPot, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), m_afficheValeurPotentiometre, SLOT(display(int)))`.
Instead, you should connect signal from an object, that is derived from QObject; add something like `valeurPotChanged(int)` signal to your class and connect it as `connect(yourObjectPtr, SIGNAL(valeurPotChanged(int)),...)`.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. But i have write a new signal : `void Dialog::valeurPotChanged(int valeur)  `whith that in : `valeur = m_valeurPot;` and i have change the signal in the connect code but that do the same things.

Comment: Sorry my signals was false but i have changed and just write the new signal in the .h and i have write `emit valeurPotChanged(m_valeurPot)` in my .cpp but that doesn't work again

Comment: Thank you that's work i had forget to change `connect(m_valeurPot...` to `connect(this..`

Answer (score 0):

Primitive data types can not emit signals!
lets begin with that...

Furthermore, in QT you pass to the connect macro/function the address of the signal emitter and the slot receiver

so this here:

```
QObject::connect(m_valeurPot, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), m_afficheValeurPotentiometre, SLOT(display(int)))
```

is not valid unless m_valeurPot is a pointer AND a QObject

since you are doing something like

```
 m_valeurPot = 0;
```

I assume that is not a pointer (could event not be a QObject... please check that)

if it is a QObject then pass the address like:

```
connect(&m_valeurPot, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), m_afficheValeurPotentiometre, SLOT(display(int)))
```

Comment: i don't have use a pointer for declare my int

Comment: must be a QObject

Comment: i have create a signal like qloq says and it work. Thank's for your help.